# Retrieving data from REST Api in Unity without lag or jitter using C#

Tags: c#, json, web-services, rest, unity-game-engine

Every 5 secs I am calling the REST using C# script. But the problem is the application lags every 10 secs(InvokeRepeating) and waits for server response and then gives out the result after the lag.

How to overcome this problem ?? I need to access a specific row in realtime so that changes is retrieved without any lag.

The Following code-snippet is used to read REST Api

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;


public class Rows {

public string description ;
public float Efficiency;
public bool IsConnected;
public string Lastconnection;
public float MTBF;
public float MTTR;
public string Name;
public float Speed;
public float TemperatureSetPoint;

}

public class GetData : MonoBehaviour 
{

string url="http:LocalHost/Data/Properties/";
string username="Administrator";
string password="admin";
string rt;


void Start () {
    JToken tok = CallWeb();
}


public JToken CallWeb()
{
     {
        var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (url);
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        string encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String (System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username+":"+password));
        httpRequest.Headers.Add ("Authorization","Basic "+encoded);
        httpRequest.Accept = "application/json";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            rt = reader.ReadToEnd();
            JObject data = JObject.Parse(rt);
            JToken token = (data["rows"][0]);
            return token;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

From the below code I access the required row and use it in unity.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class GetPropertyValues : MonoBehaviour
    {

        GetData thing = new GetData ();

        public GameObject CountText;
        public GameObject TempText;
        static string CountValue1;
        static string CountValue2;
        static string TempValue1;
        static string TempValue2;


        void Start()
        {
            JToken token = thing.CallWeb ();
            foreach (JProperty prop in token) 
            {           
                if (prop.Name == "ScrapCount") 
                { 
                    CountValue1 = prop.Value.ToString ();
                    CountText.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = "Count= "+CountValue1.ToString() ;
                    Debug.Log ("This is the Count value" + prop.Value);
                    InvokeRepeating ("countDisplay", 5, 10);
                }
                if (prop.Name == "OvenTemperature") 
                {
                    TempValue1 = prop.Value.ToString ();
                    TempText.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = TempValue1.ToString () + "'C";
                    Debug.Log ("This is the Temp value" + prop.Value);
                    InvokeRepeating ("tempDisplay", 5, 10);

                }
            }
        }

        void countDisplay()
        {
            JToken token = thing.CallThingWorx ();
            foreach (JProperty prop in token) {
                if (prop.Name == "ScrapCount") {
                    CountValue2 = prop.Value.ToString ();
                    if (CountValue1 == CountValue2) {
                        Debug.Log ("count value is still " + CountValue1);
                    }
                    else if (CountValue1 != CountValue2) {
                        CountText.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = "Count= " + CountValue2.ToString();
                        Debug.Log ("count value Changed" + CountValue2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        void tempDisplay()
        {
            JToken token = thing.CallWeb ();
            foreach (JProperty prop in token) 
            {
                if (prop.Name == "OvenTemperature") 
                {
                    TempValue2 = prop.Value.ToString ();
                    if (TempValue1 == TempValue2) 
                    {
                        Debug.Log ("Temp value is still " + TempValue1);
                    }
                    else if (TempValue1 != TempValue2) 
                    {
                        TempText.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = TempValue2.ToString() +"'C";
                        Debug.Log ("Temp value Changed" + TempValue2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you seem to be doing a synchronous request. Try to use what Unity provides

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html

```
class MyBehaviour: public MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(GetText());
    }

    IEnumerator GetText() {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://www.my-server.com");
        yield return www.Send();

        if(www.isError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else {
            // Show results as text
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

            // Or retrieve results as binary data
            byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
        }
    }
    // Edit here
    StartCoroutine(GetText());
}
```

This will keep your app running while fetching the data. The else statement is where your action will be once the download is done.

Comment: Thank a bunch :) I used your advice and got a response for only 1 time. What should I do so that the application will be constant sync with the url ?? That helps in retrieving the value that is being changed continuously???

Comment: Start the same coroutine at the end of it.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I tried this and it works perfectly fine only in the Unity Editor but not in the android app after building it.Should we have to give separate permission in the manifest to get this work in the app? if so , What needs to be added ?

Comment: Yes internet  is required. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Comment: yes, that's there  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> anything other than this ???

Comment: try with https instead. Also, do you get any report from the request? Like error or empty string? Or are you getting the xml file of the page for instance?

Comment: Just informing you again, The code is working fine in unity editor however when I build the apk and install it on my device , I'm not getting anything!! and the url is hosted in one our own servers so its not https certified and coming to your 2nd question, how to generate a log/report from the app ???

Comment: Either your device is connected to Eclipse or Android Studio and the debug will show in the console of the IDE, or you can use a GUI to print Debug. You can use this to listen to Debug message and print them on a text field https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceived.html

Comment: Also when you run in editor, check that you don't have some warning showing up that you would miss among many other debugs. Maybe it is already telling you something.