# Exception when downloading Asset Bundle on Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm getting the following exception when I build my game for android

> WWW download had an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri ==
>   null

Now I haven o idea why this is happening because it works fine in the editor. Here is the relevant code :

```
assetLoader.BundleURL = "ftp://user:pass@81.161.248.122/Unity-Uri/AssetBundles/seasonalcontent/christmas";
            assetLoader.version = 1;
            assetLoader.StartDownload();
```

and the actual download code :

```
IEnumerator DownloadAndCache()
    {
        // Wait for the Caching system to be ready
        while (!Caching.ready)
            yield return null;

        // Load the AssetBundle file from Cache if it exists with the same version or download and store it in the cache
        using (WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(BundleURL, version))
        {
            yield return www;
            if (www.error != null)
                throw new Exception("WWW download had an error:" + www.error);
            AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
            SeasonManager.assets = bundle.LoadAllAssets();
            Debug.Log("Stop");
            OnContentLoaded();
        } // memory is freed from the web stream (www.Dispose() gets called implicitly)
    }
```

Edit: I got this from the documentation : ftp:// protocol support is limited to anonymous downloads only. Is ftp not supported on android ?

Edit 2: As suggest in the comments I tried this and it results in a Login failed error :

```
 IEnumerator makeRequest()
    {
        string authorization = authenticate("username", "pass");
        string url = "ftp://ipgoeshere";


        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        www.SetRequestHeader("AUTHORIZATION", authorization);

        yield return www.Send();
        if (www.isError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            AssetBundle bundle = ((DownloadHandlerAssetBundle)www.downloadHandler).assetBundle;
            SeasonManager.assets = bundle.LoadAllAssets();
        }
    }
string authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        string auth = username + ":" + password;
        auth = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(auth));
        auth = "Basic " + auth;
        return auth;
    }
```

To clarify I've made sure that the username password and the server address are correct. I have simply removed them from the code here for obvious reasons.

Comment: Looking at the url, this looks like an authentication problem. Please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39489237/3785314) and tell me if that solves your problem.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? I want to know for future similar question.

Comment: @Programmer Hey I just got into work. I'm going to set up a ftp server with anonymous download and see if that works. Then I will try your solution.

Comment: I tried the solution from the link but I get a Login failed error and sadly I have no idea how to address it.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and post the new code you made that is throwing that error. I will then tell you if that's what I expected.