# Unity WWWForm unauthorized for azure

Tags: c#, forms, unity-game-engine, networking, request

I have to send an request with an image to Microsoft Azure Custom Vision with the header "Prediciton-Key" -> myKey  and the body should be an image (binary data).

First of all i tryed with postman and it works fine, but when i put it on Unity ,i get an error :401 Unauthorized.

Does anyone know why? (i put the api key as string)

```
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.headers.Add("Prediction-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    form.AddBinaryData("fileUpload", texture.EncodeToPNG());

   UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequest.Post(link,form);

    yield return req.SendWebRequest();
```

Comment: `Prediciton-Key` That is a different spelling to your code.

Comment: Use a sniffer and compare postman results with your results.  There is probably a difference in the header in the request.  Solution is to make you headers look like the postman headers.

Comment: In the instructions is highlighted "Prediction-Key"
It's a little weird because if i use WWW instead of UnityWebRequest all is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/rest-api-tutorial) they actually didn't show any example for using the `Prediction-Key` but I guess it works similar to the examples with `Training-Key` e.g.:

```
curl -X POST "https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v2.0/Training/projects/{projectId}/tags?name=cat" -H "Training-Key: $TRAININGKEY" --data-ascii ""
```

The header after `-H` is a header added to the http-request itself not as a header field within the `form`.

I'm pretty sure you have to use a base64 encoded string similar to when adding authorization headers ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482954/unitywebrequest-embedding-user-password-data-for-http-basic-authentication-not))

```
string Base64String(string key)
{
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(key));
}
```

and than use it [`req.SetRequestHeader`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader.html) in order to authorize the http-request itself not as header in the form:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddBinaryData("fileUpload", texture.EncodeToPNG());

UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequest.Post(link,form);
req.SetRequestHeader("Prediction-Key", Base64String("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

yield return req.SendWebRequest();
```

Comment: Thx!
The weird part is that is working with WWW instead of UnityWebRequest