# How to update user picture using PUT method in Unity3D

Tags: c#, rest, unity-game-engine, client-server

I'm a beginner in Unity3D; i have to develop a mobile app and i need to manage user profile data; i have to communicate these data with server using REST services.
Everything works fine when i send Json (eg name, email, phone number, etc.) from my app, but I can't update the profile picture.

What i need is:
Content-Type = multipart/form-data
key="profile_picture", value=file_to_upload (not the path)

I read a lot about networking in Unity and tried different combinations of UnityWebRequest, List, WWWform but nothing seems to work for this kind of PUT service.

```
UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest(URL + user.email, "PUT");
    www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    www.SetRequestHeader("AUTHORIZATION", authorization);
    //i think here i'm missing the correct way to set up the content
```

I can correctly simulate the update from Postman, so it's not a problem with server; i'm pretty sure that the problem is that i can't convert this logic inside the app.

Upload from Postman correctly working(1)

[image]

Upload from Postman correctly working(2)

[image]

Any kind of help and code suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: There is a helper class upload handler https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UploadHandler.html. Perhaps that helps?

Comment: Yes, that should be the way, but i'm missing the correct way to set up the upload handler, because i need something like a form with a KEY=VALUE structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Put](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-UploadingRawData.html) you usually only send file data but without a form.

You can add a multipart form using [UnityWebRequest.Post](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html)

```
IEnumerator Upload() 
{
    List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
    formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("profile_picture", byte[], "example.png", "image/png"));

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, formData);

    // change the method name
    www.method = "PUT"; 

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.error) 
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else 
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    }
}
```

using a [MultipartFormFileSection](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormFileSection-ctor.html)

---

Or alternatively you can use a [WWWForm](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormFileSection-ctor.html)

```
IEnumerator Upload()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddBinaryData("profile_picture", bytes, "filename.png", "image/png");

    // Upload via post request
    var www = UnityWebRequest.Post(screenShotURL, form);

    // change the method name
    www.method = "PUT";        

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.error) 
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else 
    {
        Debug.Log("Finished Uploading Screenshot");
    }
}
```

using [WWWForm.AddBinaryData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.AddBinaryData.html)

---

Note that for user authentication you have to encode your credentials properly:

```
string authenticate(string username, string password)
{
    string auth = username + ":" + password;
    auth = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(auth));
    auth = "Basic " + auth;
    return auth;
}

www.SetRequestHeader("AUTHORIZATION", authenticate("user", "password"));
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482954/unitywebrequest-embedding-user-password-data-for-http-basic-authentication-not))

Comment: That's just better than what i tried, but it bring me to the same error:
if i use POST request i have Error 405, because POST request is not implemented on server. On the other side, if i try tu upload only the file i have Error 500.
Using postman, i can correctly use PUT service

Comment: Afaik there is no standard way for sending multiform data with PUT. You might however try to simply change the method by using somehing like `www.method = "PUT";`

Comment: I just included user authentication, i have problems only in this case

Comment: This is a great workaround. Please keep in mind that MultipartFormFileSection may require all the "four paramaters" as specified by derHugo